# Getting Ethereum amount from Ethers.js Contract Transfer Event

Tags: ether, etherscan, ethers.js

I am working on building a simple Twitter bot to tweet out sales that occur on an NFT's Smart Contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0xbd3531da5cf5857e7cfaa92426877b022e612cf8) by listening to the `Transfer` event and tweeting out the information from the event subscription.

After following a tutorial in the Ethers.js docs (https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/contract/example/-%23-example-erc-20-contract--connecting-to-a-contract), it looks like I am able to see Transfer events output, but I am not sure how to get the actual Ethereum value (price) from the transaction. It looks like the parameters are `to`, `from`, and the mint number of the NFT collection.

I will post the event listened code, as well as the response. Please let me know if anyone knows what I am missing, thanks!

**Event Listener**

```
const abi = await getContractAbi();
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(WSS_PROVIDER);
const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, provider);

contract.on("Transfer", (from, to, amount, value, event) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
});
```

**Output**

```
{
  "blockNumber": 13553616,
  "blockHash": "0xa49016edacc2cdde0f49510fec7af16be42fd7d72f688b0a83f9afcb6d6dae39",
  "transactionIndex": 214,
  "removed": false,
  "address": "0xBd3531dA5CF5857e7CfAA92426877b022e612cf8",
  "data": "0x",
  "topics": [
    "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
    "0x00000000000000000000000046434f8f0b6d31a6a3ace9307077f5699eab2a08",
    "0x00000000000000000000000044f63ba8637466015a8510dc40f384013d4dfbcc",
    "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018d"
  ],
  "transactionHash": "0x49a1b9af049ff10cc8e61ad49499c3615b1455a33c9cda6cc0390142d0058281",
  "logIndex": 483,
  "event": "Transfer",
  "eventSignature": "Transfer(address,address,uint256)",
  "args": [
    "0x46434f8f0b6d31A6A3aCe9307077F5699eab2a08",
    "0x44f63bA8637466015A8510dc40f384013D4DfBcC",
    { "type": "BigNumber", "hex": "0x018d" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather listen for the ordersMatched event, which include a price param (see the 3d log event: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x49a1b9af049ff10cc8e61ad49499c3615b1455a33c9cda6cc0390142d0058281#eventlog or the actual event in wyvernEngine : https://etherscan.io/address/0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b#code line450).

Comment: It looks like I can't listen to that event? I get an error whenever I try, and when I output the contract, it looks like the only events are listed below:
events: {
      'Approval(address,address,uint256)': [EventFragment],
      'ApprovalForAll(address,address,bool)': [EventFragment],
      'CreatePenguin(uint256)': [EventFragment],
      'OwnershipTransferred(address,address)': [EventFragment],
      'Paused(address)': [EventFragment],
      'Transfer(address,address,uint256)': [EventFragment],
      'Unpaused(address)': [EventFragment]
},